# update favourite posts count when there is new favourite post

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm using "[WP Favourite posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-favorite-posts/)" wordpress plugin.

I have a place in my header where I’m showing the total count of favourited posts for current user. I did it with below code:

```
<?php echo sizeof(wpfp_get_users_favorites()); ?>
```

So now when clicked on “Add to favourite” button in the page, I want to update this count automatically. But don't know which action to use. How can I do that?

Comment: You will need to tie into the click action of the favorite button and then either reload the page or load the new count via AJAX. If you have issues doing that post your code attempt and the community can help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I'm using. Note that each link is inside a td, but you can change the CSS attribute of the link as well.

```
(jQuery)("a.wpfp-link").live( "click", function() {
if ((jQuery)(this).closest('td').hasClass('cellhighlight')=== true)
{
        (jQuery)(this).closest('td').removeClass('cellhighlight');
}
else
{
    (jQuery)(this).closest('td').addClass('cellhighlight'); 
}
var numItems = (jQuery)('.cellhighlight').length;
```